# sticky footer inside tow div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a sticky footer that always stay at the bottom. But my footer is not direct child of the first div, its the second child. Like This https://jsfiddle.net/bduswush/

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
    <div id="inner-wrap">
        <div class="head">This is head</div>
        <div class="content">This is body</div>
        <div class="footer">This is footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is here - it does not take the full height of device screen and content div is overlapped by the footer. I want to left the footer height auto. Is there any solution?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a `height` and `width` to `html` and `body` tags.

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
#outer-wrap {
 height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
#inner-wrap {
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
  background: #00b;
}
.footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-wrap">
  <div id="inner-wrap">
   <div class="head">This is head</div>
   <div class="content">This is body</div>
   <div class="footer">This is footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is because when you use `height` and `width` with percentages, it take its value from its parent so if you do not set a value to the `height` and `width` of its parent it cannot fill the space required.

Comment: true that `height`, but why `width`?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta I always set it on html and body tags to get the full available space. Then if I need lower width I set a container to wrap it. Just a personal habit.

Comment: Thats works great on Pc, but when i go to mobile i cannot scroll down my content as the #outer-wrap is fixed to 100%.

Comment: @aziz Try using `min-height: 100%`.

Comment: And if i set outer-wrap height to min-height: 100%, then the footer content overlap again with the .content area and and it it  stay at the bottom of content area not at the device screen bottom.

Comment: @aziz Can you provide the html and css code that you have right now?

Comment: Actually I take the menu form github and use it to my project. here is the link of the source. [link](https://github.com/dbushell/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu)

Comment: @aziz Then you do not have the same behaviour as in your question because you add a plugin. I think you should open a new one with the new issue.

Comment: Here is my code., please see it bro. I cannot scroll down in mobile device. Because I make #outer-wrap height:100%. Only #inner-wrap, #outer-wrap, footer[role="contentinfo"] are necessary in the css i provide. Thanks [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a775zkqw/)

Comment: @aziz Look it now. Here is your [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a775zkqw/1/).

Comment: I am really sorry bro, It works now in mobile, but in pc it;s right below the content,  not at the bottom at the device screen. Please check it bro. and thank you a lot cause you are wasting your valuable time for me.

Comment: @aziz So what you want is that the footer will be always fixed on the bottom of your screen and not after the content?

Comment: i want the footer will be at the bottom of the screen and in mobile device it will be at the bottom of content.

Comment: @aziz Then you can display your footer as `position: fixed` and set it on the bottom of the screen with `bottom: 0;`. Look at this new [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a775zkqw/2/)